# VS code debugger doesn't open terminal

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to create a cpp environment on vs code. The build works, .exe gets generated, but the debugger doesn't seem to work. When I click on the run debug option, another terminal gets open with a message (attached in the screenshot). The code which I'm running is a simple hello world example. No terminal with Hello World is opened by the debugger. Hello world is supposed to be displayed in the screenshot of ***terminal 2*** but another message gets printed, which I got no clue about.

[Terminal 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGuzg.jpg)

[Terminal 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWqNK.jpg)

This is the code for the config files:

**task.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "sample.cpp"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:\\Users\\Amey\\Desktop\\work\\Programming\\C++\\a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you looking at the Debug tab? Try changing to `"externalConsole": true,`.